# How to merge records based on consective fields in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a source like below table:

```
+---------+--+--------+--+---------+--+--+------+
|   ID    |  | SEQ_NO |  | UNIT_ID |  |  | D_ID |
+---------+--+--------+--+---------+--+--+------+
| 7979092 |  |      1 |  |      99 |  |  |  759 |
| 7979092 |  |      2 |  |      -1 |  |  |  869 |
| 7979092 |  |      3 |  |      -1 |  |  |  927 |
| 7979092 |  |      4 |  |      -1 |  |  |  812 |
| 7979092 |  |      5 |  |      99 |  |  |  900 |
| 7979092 |  |      6 |  |      99 |  |  |  891 |
| 7979092 |  |      7 |  |      -1 |  |  |  785 |
| 7979092 |  |      8 |  |      -1 |  |  |  762 |
| 7979092 |  |      9 |  |      -1 |  |  |  923 |
+---------+--+--------+--+---------+--+--+------+
```

I have to merge the rows when consecutive unit_id has same value. We should take max(D_id) when we consolidate the rows. Expected output is:

```
+---------+---------+------+
|   ID    | UNIT_ID | D_ID |
+---------+---------+------+
| 7979092 |      99 |  759 |
| 7979092 |      -1 |  927 |
| 7979092 |      99 |  900 |
| 7979092 |      -1 |  923 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

I have tried to find the solution using Teradata ordered analytical function, but did not find the solution. I use Teradata 16.

Thank You.

Comment: Is the `SEQ_NO` actually a sequence with no gaps?

Comment: Yes @dnoeth. It is basically derived field and acts as sk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is a bit quirky, it's based on two sequences created by different sort orders:

```
SELECT
   ID
  ,UNIT_ID
  ,Max(D_ID)
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      ID
     ,SEQ_NO
     ,UNIT_ID
     ,D_ID
     -- assign the same value to consecutive UNIT_IDs
     ,SEQ_NO -
      Row_Number()
      Over(PARTITION BY ID, UNIT_ID 
           ORDER BY SEQ_NO) AS grp
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1,2,grp
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth for your reply. As per this sql , row_number groups UNIT_ID with -1 into one number and other group with UNIT_ID= 99 into another set. But I want unique group number to be created whenever value of UNIT_ID is changed. I tried using this - ,sum(case when UNIT_ID <> UNIT_ID_prev then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID,UNIT_ID order by SEQ_NO rows unbounded preceding). But it does not provide the required output.

Comment: Did you actually run my query? Simply run the inner Select to see how a new `grp` is assigned whenever the unit id changes.

Comment: I am so sorry, You are always Right ! My previous SQL had an issue. It works fine as expected!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RESET WHEN` to dynamically create groups within the window.  Here's one way to do it:

```sql
select ID, UNIT_ID,
  max(D_ID) over(
    partition by ID order by SEQ_NO 
    reset when UNIT_ID <> UNIT_ID_prev -- Create new group for new value
  ) as D_ID
from (
  select ID, SEQ_NO, UNIT_ID, D_ID, 
    lag(UNIT_ID) over(partition by ID order by SEQ_NO) as UNIT_ID_prev -- Previous value
  from MY_TABLE
) src
qualify row_number() over(
  partition by ID order by SEQ_NO 
  reset when UNIT_ID <> UNIT_ID_prev -- Match original max() window
) = 1 -- One row per group (similar to DISTINCT)
```

Comment: Thanks your solution. Your sql works fine when I changed  the sql to use max and qualify inside a single query.